# Waterproofing products

Tags: sensor, temperature, waterproof

Does anyone know of a product that can be used for waterproofing electronics and exposed wiring that is suitable for submersion for potentially long periods?

More specifically, I am looking for a way to coat either thermocouples or thermistors that may be mounted on small PCBs or sometimes just soldered to the end of connecting wires.

I need the said devices to measure water temperature with fairly fast response time but not be affected by the conductivity of the water.

Comment: What you are looking for called PCB encapsulation or potting. Essentially embedding it in a block or blob of epoxy. Conformal coatings won't work here because of actual submersion. Use epoxy made for the purpose since epoxy can shrink as it cures (and with temperature changes) and impart stress on compoments and the PCB. There are thermally conductive potting epoxies as well. You might want to check that the epoxy is actually rated for submersion. The wiring insulation too. Most seemingly "waterproof" materials aren't because water will eventually permeate through it when submerged.

Comment: Yeah I have considered using a potting compound, but it generally makes the response a lot slower (due to the added mass around the sensor)

Comment: I think a bare thermocouple will work immersed in water. The voltage is so small that the water conductivity doesn't really affect the measurement. At least that has been my experience. I haven't done careful testing.

Comment: @Angus  Can you describe your entire application?  Why do you want to measure water temperature?  For how long?  In what kind of body of water?  What are you going to do with the measurements?

Comment: It is very common for questions here to say "potentially long periods" without giving any indication what a long period is. it is an easy mistake to make. But some people may consider 10 minutes to be a long period, and some may consider 3 years to be a long period. Same goes for "fairly fast response time". I think Nick is right to ask for much more information because there may be a better way to do whatever you are trying to do than stick a thermistor in a container of water. But at a minimum, please define "long periods" and "fairly fast".

Comment: https://www.omega.com/pptst/OL-708.html#order

Comment: Ok, I work at the ANU in Canberra (Australia) in a fluid dynamics laboratory. we work mostly on ocean current modelling (oceanography)  
part of this is modelling thermal currents in bodies of water. for this, we generally use very fine tipped thermistors with response times from 7ms  to 1sec. these are hooked up through a bridge-amplifier to data acquisition cards for computer logging. This can take anywhere from a few minutes, to days-weeks-months.  
https://www.amphenol-sensors.com/en/thermometrics/ntc-thermistors/glass/3337-fp-series

Comment: although these are great for response and accuracy they are very easily broken and creating a good waterproof seal between the glass and mounting tubes can prove challenging. we are also currently looking into using thermocouples as a more physically robust way to measure temperature but are faced with a similar problem with sealing/waterproofing, as getting water in the connecting wires/joins
does cause voltage drift.

Comment: So I was thinking a good solution could be to find some sort of lacquer or resin we could use to coat the finished wiring connections to ensure they stay sealed dry. But finding such a product has been more challenging than I first thought.

Comment: A bit different than what I imagined. There are a lot of hermetically sealed thermistors available (you can look on digikey). But getting something very low mass may be challenging. One product I worked on used plastic potted thermistors embedded in a laminated structure. Occasionally they would fail, seemingly due to moisture (heat would cause them to return to normal behavior) but I could never get new ones to fail just by immersing them. So I am not optimistic about laquer or polymer potting. Hermetically sealed NTC sensors are available, but as you say, the thermal mass is large.

Comment: The thinnest waterproofing I have found is a diamond coat DUREX Polyurethane coating that dries in minutes and hardens in a couple of hours to full strength. Very low viscosity and I apply 3 coats . You can spray or brush it. I allowed 30 minutes between coats. For Chrysler, we used a thicker dip for the whole board.

Answer (score 1):

PCB encapsulation, potting or coating is usually against short time water contact, most potty [will absorb moisture](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6748283) over time and ultimately get to the PCB over time if immersed.

Water will also be absorbed through the cables and you need to use cables that are specifically designed to be under water.

The correct way is to use a waterproof enclosure designed for it and that has seals.

For measuring the water temperature, you may find aluminium or stainless steel enclosure and you simply need to connect the probe to the wall of the enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

Raytech Magic Gel is designed to cover electrical equipment for underwater use.

https://www.raytech.it/product/low-voltage/magic-gel?lang=en

Comment: I'm not even sure that's technically true since the test for IP68 only requires submersion for 30 minutes.

Comment: @Toor  Not to nitpick.  IP67 requires 30 minutes submersion.  For IP68, you (the manugfacturer) specify how long the submersion should be (it needs to be longer than 30 minutes).  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code#Second_digit:_Liquid_ingress_protection).

Comment: Perhaps the manufacturer doesn't want to overpromise.  I received this message from a customer a few days ago: "The gel is fantastic. We had a site flood where the boxes were 4 m underwater. When the levels finally dropped, the boxes were still running perfectly even though water got into the box. Great for us that we didn’t need to dry them out/ replace them and that we carried on collecting data during that time."